# Unprocessable Entity while Creating Session in Quickblox

Tags: rest, quickblox

I'm Always getting same exception can somebody help me out to resolve this?

```
POST request for "https://api.quickblox.com/session" resulted in 422 (Unprocessable Entity); invoking error handler
```

Request data:

```
<{timestamp=1421688858744, nonce=1667154, application_id=16877, auth_key=WVrgfqUuDPCQhAD, signature=b50a52268e02ed7afff75640afa9782702e8d7c5},{Content-Type=[application/json], QuickBlox-REST-API-Version=[0.1.0]}>
```

Comment: Can you provide some code how you do it

Comment: Random randomGenerator = new Random();
  Integer randomInt = randomGenerator.nextInt(10000000);

  Long timestamp = Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis();

  String postData = "application_id=" + applicationId;
  postData += "&auth_key=" + authKey;
  postData += "&timestamp="+ timestamp;
  postData+="&nonce"+randomInt;
  try {
  String signature = HmacSha1Signature.calculateRFC2104HMAC(postData, authSecret);
  
   parameterToWS.put("application_id", applicationId);

  parameterToWS.put("auth_key", authKey);

  parameterToWS.put("timestamp", timestamp.toString());
Added All Params to map

Comment: Please add to the original post, not a comment